# "as were" is it inverted or something else?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, inversion

> Dildos and other sexual aids are frequently mentioned in ancient
> literature and depicted on pottery, while didactic sex manuals were
> popular, **as were** more general advice books such as the Ars Amatoria

I am confused by "as were", I guess this is a kind of inverted sentence, maybe a regular order would be

> **as** more general advice books such as the Ars Amatoria **were**

but I am not sure about my guess, can anybody help me parse this sentence?

Comment: it is saying 'didactic sex manuals were popular and more general advice books such as the Ars Amatoria were ALSO popular'. 'As' is used to mean 'at the same time'.

Comment: As a general rule, this kind of "inversion" (reversing subject and object after ***as***) is far more likely in relatively formal contexts. Hence ***He's here, as am I*** is more formal / literary than ***...as I am*** (but those are *both* much more formal than ***...and so am I***). It's just a stylistic choice, that doesn't affect the meaning.

Comment: 'In the same way' rather than 'at the same time'.

Answer (score 2):

This is an inversion, triggered by the word "as".  The same inversion can also be triggered by "so".

> Italy produces many excellent wines, as does Spain.

(= and Spain does too)  ([example online](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/11/inversion-with-so-such-and-as-exercises.html))

This is fairly formal.  The phrase following "as" is the subject, and would take the subject form of the verb and pronoun: "He is happy, as am I".

So in your example the phrase "more general books...Ars Amatoria" is the subject of the clause, "were" is the verb and heads the clause, the complement is implied from the previous phrase to be "popular". The meaning is, "Sex manuals were popular and more general books were popular too."

Comment: thank your answer,your are very helpful,while so many people in this site did't take my question seriously